# OLE DB Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, business-objects

I tried to create a connection for BusinessObjects universe.
However, I got the following error message:

- OLE DB Provider CLSID not specified or erroneous

Also I took a look at ODBC Data sources -> Drivers. The SQL Native CLient is installed.
I am trying to connect to MS SQL Server 2008.
Furthermore, the ODBC connection is functioning from my computer. But the created connection is OLE DB, and it gives me this error. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?p=714216) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the client. Althoug I installed the 2012 MS SQL client the connection did not function. When I installed the 2008 MS SQL client, it functioned.